# Odd numbers with $\varphi(n)/n < 1/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, totient-function

*The topic was also discussed in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/320451/30186).*

From $\varphi(n)/n = \prod_{p|n}(1-1/p)$ ([Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler%27s_product_formula)) one concludes that even numbers $n$ must have $\varphi(n)/n \leq 1/2$ because the product contains the factor $1/2$ and cannot be larger than that.

But not all odd numbers have $\varphi(n)/n > 1/2$. The smallest number that hasn't is $105$.

You can see the exceptions as bright stars when plotting $\varphi(n)/n$ on a [square spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) (where odd and even numbers build a checkerboard pattern), but only, when $\varphi(n)/n > 1/2$:

[image]

I wonder if and how one could enumerate or characterize all odd numbers for which $\varphi(n)/n < 1/2$.

This is how one could proceed: Start with an empty list. Determine the smallest square-free odd number $n$ with $\varphi(n)/n < 1/2$ which is not on the list and add it to the list together with its odd multiples. Then find the next, and the next, and so on. The list starts with

- $105 = 3\cdot 5 \cdot 7$ and its odd multiples $315, 525, 735,...$
- $165 = 3\cdot 5 \cdot 11$ and its odd multiples $495,825,1155,...$
- $195 = 3\cdot 5 \cdot 13$ and its odd multiples $195,585,975,1365,...$

These numbers can be seen as white stars (above).

Then a jump occurs:

- $3,003 = 3\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$ and its odd multiples $9009, 15015, 21021,  ...$
- $3,927 = 3\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$ and its odd multiples $11781, 19635, 27489 ...$
- $4,389 = 3\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 19$ and its odd multiples $13167, 21945, 30723, ...$
- $4,641 = 3\cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$ and its odd multiples $13923, 23205, 32487, ...$
- $5,187 = 3\cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19$ and its odd multiples $15561, 25935, 36309, ...$
- $5,313= 3\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 23$ and its odd multiples $15939, 26565, 37191, ...$

The four smallest of these numbers can be seen as yellow stars (above).

Then the numbers $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot p$ follow for $23 \leq p \leq 251$, the largest one being $64,005$.

Then a larger jump occurs:

- $138,567 = 3\cdot  11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 $

---

Note that in the first group of numbers (divisible by $3$ and $5$) all differences are multiples of $30 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5$. That's because all numbers are multiples of $15$ and the even multiples are omitted. In the second
group (divisible by $3$ and $7$) all differences are multiples of $42 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 7$.

---

There are several questions related to these findings:

> 1. <strike>Are there "smallest numbers" I missed?</strike>  
>    <sub>This question has been answered thanks to Robert Israel's link to [OEIS A119433](https://oeis.org/A119433). I've edited my post accordingly.</sub>
> 2. How do I systematically find the next "smallest number"?
> 3. After ordering the first group, the maximal factor of consecutive numbers in this group is $7$, i.e. when $n_{k+1} = n_k + a\cdot 30$
>    then $1 \leq a \leq 7$. Furthermore, all factors $1 \leq a \leq 7$ do occur. I wonder why this is so and how to prove it?
> 4. What's the maximal factor for the second group?
> 5. Which other properties do odd numbers with $\varphi(n)/n < 1/2$ share with even numbers? (They might be considered "quasi-even".)

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A119434](https://oeis.org/A119434) and [A119433](https://oeis.org/A119433).

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Thanks, I've seen it. But does it help to answer my question? (Ah, I see that you are the author of this OEIS entry. Very pleased!)

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I see, the second sequence answers question 1: There are lots of numbers $5,313<n<138,567$ which do qualify, the first one is $5,865 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 17 \cdot 23$. And it may also give me hint to answer question 2.

Comment: I have already given you a proof for 3. in a comment on MathOverflow. You similarly show $5$ is the maximum for second group (I haven't numerically checked if all occur, I suspect they do)

Comment: @Wojowu. Yes, I saw it, thanks again. But to be honest I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: The largest [primitive element of A119432](https://oeis.org/A119433/b119433.txt) $n < 138,567$ is $64,005 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 17\cdot 251$.

Comment: One of $n_k+30,\dots,n_k+7\cdot 30$ will be divisible by $7$, since those numbers have distinct residues modulo $7$. That number is also divisible by $3$ and $5$. Therefore we have $\varphi(n)/n\leq(1-1/3)(1-1/5)(1-1/7)<1/2$. Would you like me to elaborate on some step?

Comment: @Wojowu. No, thanks, now I see! I haven't seen that those numbers have distinct residues modulo 7.

Comment: @Wojowu: Sorry, but I'm not through with it, yet. Is this the right argument: $7$ is the number for $3\cdot 5 = 15$ because $7$ is the smallest (prime?) number  coprime to $2$ and $15$? $5$ is the number for $3\cdot 7 = 21$ because $5$ is the smallest (prime?) number coprime to $2$ and $21$?

Comment: You need to note that $7\cdot 15$ (respectively, $5\cdot 21$) is an exception, hence so is every multiple of it, and $7$ (respectively, $5$) is the smallest number for which this holds. It need not be a prime if you consider other primes in place of $3,5$ (respectively, $3,7$)

Comment: @Wojowu: How then do I find the number for $3,5,17$, by which expression? By my argument it would be $7$ (the smallest number coprime to $2$ and $255$, happens to be prime) - and indeed $1785 = 7\cdot 255$ is an exception.

Comment: Consider finding the number for just $3$. You look for the smallest number $k$ relatively prime to $2$ and $3$ for which $3k$ is an exception. The answer here is $35$.

Comment: @Wojowu That's a nice example for a non-prime number. Now I finally got it.

Comment: The smallest odd number that is not a multiple of $3$ for which $\frac{\phi(n)}n\lt\frac12$ is $37182145$.

Comment: @robjohn - I had this in my original question - $37,182,145 = 5⋅7⋅11⋅13⋅17⋅19⋅23$ - but deleted it because it came out of the blue. But with your explicit remark  "smallest exception not a multiple of $3$" it would have made sense. Thanks anyway. (Don't you find it an astonishlingly large number?)

Comment: @HansStricker: Just wait: the smallest odd number that is not a multiple of $3$ or $5$ for which $\frac{\phi(n)}n\lt\frac12$ is $3909612711980232366109$.

Comment: I have taken a liberty of adding a link to the related MO question. People should be aware that related questions have already been discussed at length so that they don't repeat what was already said (for instance, I have essentially already said what robjohn's past two comments say in the previous question)

Comment: Fair enough, thank you.

Comment: @robjohn How did you prove this ?

Comment: @Peter: One just multiplies $\left(1-\frac17\right)\left(1-\frac1{11}\right)\left(1-\frac1{13}\right)\left(1-\frac1{17}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{61}\right)$ until the product becomes less than $\frac12$. Then compute $7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdots61$.

Comment: You can also use any other fraction, like $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \le \frac{4}{21}$ or something.