# On numbers with small $\varphi(n)/n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, totient-function

Let $\Phi(n) = \varphi(n)/n = \prod_{p|n}(p-1)/p$ be the "normalized totient" of $n$.

Some facts:

- $\Phi(p) = (p-1)/p < 1$ for prime numbers with $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\Phi(p) = 1$
- $\Phi(n) = 1/2$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$
- $\Phi(n) < 1/2$ for all even $n$ that are not powers of $2$ and [some odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068771/odd-numbers-with-varphin-n-1-2) $n$
- if $\Phi(n) > 1/2$ then $n$ is odd

I have some questions concerning numbers with $\Phi(n) < 1/2$:

> - Are there numbers with arbitrary small $\Phi(n)$? Or is there a lower bound $\Phi_{\text{min}} > 0$?
> - Are there odd numbers with arbitrary small $\Phi(n)$?
> - How can this astonishing regularity been explained when displaying in a square spiral only those numbers with $\Phi(n) < 1/3$ – a regular pattern of triples pointing right, down, left, up clockwise (with some irregularily distributed [defects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_defect) of course):

[image]

Note that the regular background pattern vanishes when choosing values other than 1/3, e.g. 0.3 (left) or 0.4 (right):

[image]
[image]

Since the cases [$\Phi(n) < 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068771/odd-numbers-with-varphin-n-1-2) and $\Phi(n) < 1/3$ display regular patterns, one might suspect that also $\Phi(n) < 1/5$ gives rise to some regularity. But the numbers envolved in creating that pattern are too big, so I cannot visualize it.

> - Supposed one would visualize $\Phi(n) < 1/5$ which regular pattern would emerge (if any)?

Comment: Perhaps you should change the symbol for that normalization, as it is easy, I think, to confuse with Euler's function. Perhaps something like $\;\Phi(n)\;$ or perhaps even $\;\Psi(n)\;$ .

Comment: Done, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Even for odd $n$, the value can get arbitary small since the product $$\prod_{p\ prime} \frac{p-1}{p}$$ diverges to $0$

Comment: What might help for a deeper analyze is that we can replace $n$ by its radical (the product of the primes dividing $n$)

Comment: @Peter: Why do you say "diverges to $0$"? Don't you mean "converges"?

Comment: In the case of a product, "convergence" means that the value is non-zero. Important is that the product becomes arbitary small , if we consider more and more primes.

Comment: @Peter: Ah, I didn't know that (one calls convergence to zero "divergence"), now I know. But the product gets smaller very, very slowly, doesn't it? $\prod_{p \leq 739} (p-1)/p$ which corresponds to the number $\prod_{p \leq 739} p \approx 4\cdot 10^{306}$ is still $\approx 0.081$

Comment: @Peter: Which product?

Comment: For more details, google Mertens' theorems.

Comment: @Peter: On the left side $p$ is a bound variable. What does it mean on the right side?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. We have $$\prod_{p\ prime, p\le x} \frac{p-1}{p}\approx \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(x)}$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni-constant.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems simple: Having a closer look at the numbers in the spiral reveals that most of them are - not surprisingly - multiples of $6 = 2\cdot 3$:

[image]

And the spiral forces the multiples of $6$ to arrange in triples (except along the lower right diagonal):

[image]

But not all multiples of $6$ have $\Phi(n) < 1/3$, e.g. $n = 2^k\cdot 3$, and not all $n$ with $\Phi(n) < 1/3$ are multiples of $6$, the smallest one being $770 = 2\cdot 5\cdot 7 \cdot 11$.

To answer partly the last of my questions: This is how the integers divisible by 8 and 10 are distributed (the second picture giving the blueprint for the case $\Phi(n) < 1/5$):

[image]
[image]

Note that in the right picture the "arrows" (5-tuples) go counter-clockwise.